# Can I cause BASH to echo all source when it is invoked?

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have a complex bash script:

```
x.sh
#! /bin/bash
. include/this/script.sh
. include/this/other/script.sh 
...
foo="foo$bar"
echo $foo
```

Is there some setting or way to cause BASH to echo all the source code it sources, including the main script when I invoke it, so I know exactly what is going on?

Comment: Put `set -x` under the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`,).

Comment: `set -x` should do it

Comment: Without modifying the script: Run it by `bash -x x.sh` or `bash -v x.sh`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way, without debugging garbage:

```
set -v
. include/this/script.sh
. include/this/other/script.sh
```

Comment: Note that `set -v` will print commands *before parsing*, while `set -x` prints them *after* parsing. So in OP's example, `-v` would print `foo="foo$bar"` while `-x` would print `foo='foowhatever $bar expanded to'`. You can set both, to get both versions of each command.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I am looking for the code rather than the executed content.  So I want to see everything that is sourced rather than just the content that is run. I am guessing that `-x` will, yes, expand everything *that is run* but `-v` will print everything *that is defined*.  Maybe I have it wrong? I haven't had a chance to test everything.

Comment: So, your choice is good ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what's being executed, you can `set -x`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -x
. include/this/script.sh
. include/this/other/script.sh 

foo="foo$bar"
echo $foo
```

`set -x` - After expanding each simple command, `for` command, `case` command, `select` command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of `PS4`, followed by the command and its expanded  arguments or associated word list.